# Can I use any sort of pumpkin for pumpkin pie?

Tags: pie, pumpkin

When I'm making a pumpkin pie, does it matter what sort of pumpkin I use? Are the specific varieties that are more suited to pies or can I just use any pumpkin?

Comment: I use acorn squashes. Makes for a tastier pie. Hubbard is good too.You never know if those small pumpkins were grown for cooking, or just came from the wrong end of a row in a pumpkin patch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use all sorts of pumpkins and squashes (a *Cucurbita moschata* or *Cucurbita pepo* may be called either, depending on variety) to make a pie.  The Halloween types may not be the best choice: they tend to be stringy, not very sweet, and sometimes over treated with pesticides. Instead look for the small varieties (around 5 lbs.) called Sugar, Long Pie, or Trickster.

When making the pumpkin purée for a pie from scratch it is important to deal with the water content of the pumpkin.  After you [bake, cool, and purée the pumpkin](http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/Fresh-Pumpkin-Puree-105640), you may need to use a cheesecloth to wring the purée.

Comment: I second the advice to steer clear of the jack-o-lantern style pumpkins and go for the smaller "pie" pumpkins. 

And you will *definitely* want to let the pumpkin purée sit in a colander or strainer for a few hours before using.

Comment: I let the puree set in a colander for 2 days to drain.
Baking really is the way to go to cook the pumpkin

Answer (score 4):

The advice is to stay clear of the ones specifically [tuned for halloween](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317150938/http://www.ochef.com/847.htm). To a first approximation, if you find it in the grocery, it's good.